# link_to redirect to a wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a layout for my admin area called 'layout_admin' . In 'layout_admin', I have :

```
<li><%= link_to 'Contenu', :action=>'index', :controller=>'contents' %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Petitions', :controller => 'petitions', :action => 'index' %></li>
```

The first link for Contenu works fine, but the second one (for petitions) drives me to a strange error :

> Routing Error 
>   No route matches {:controller=>"admin/**edito**"}

In the address bar I have : localhost:3000/admin/petitions

In routes.rb  I have :

```
namespace :admin do resources :petitions 
end
```

I must also precise that "edito" is another controller outside the admin area which has one action "index". In routes.rb I have `get "edito/index"` concerning edito_controller.

Does somebody have an idea of the source of the problem ?
Thansk.

Full Rake routes :

```
        temoignages GET    /temoignages(.:format)              temoignages#index

                POST   /temoignages(.:format)              temoignages#create
 new_temoignage GET    /temoignages/new(.:format)          temoignages#new
edit_temoignage GET    /temoignages/:id/edit(.:format)     temoignages#edit
     temoignage GET    /temoignages/:id(.:format)          temoignages#show
                PUT    /temoignages/:id(.:format)          temoignages#update
                DELETE /temoignages/:id(.:format)          temoignages#destroy
admin_petitions GET    /admin/petitions(.:format)          admin/petitions#index
                POST   /admin/petitions(.:format)          admin/petitions#create
new_admin_petition GET    /admin/petitions/new(.:format)      admin/petitions#new
edit_admin_petition GET    /admin/petitions/:id/edit(.:format) admin/petitions#edit
 admin_petition GET    /admin/petitions/:id(.:format)      admin/petitions#show
                PUT    /admin/petitions/:id(.:format)      admin/petitions#update
                DELETE /admin/petitions/:id(.:format)      admin/petitions#destroy
 admin_contents GET    /admin/contents(.:format)           admin/contents#index
                POST   /admin/contents(.:format)           admin/contents#create
new_admin_content GET    /admin/contents/new(.:format)       admin/contents#new
edit_admin_content GET    /admin/contents/:id/edit(.:format)  admin/contents#edit
  admin_content GET    /admin/contents/:id(.:format)       admin/contents#show
                PUT    /admin/contents/:id(.:format)       admin/contents#update
                DELETE /admin/contents/:id(.:format)       admin/contents#destroy
    admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)              admin/posts#index

                POST   /admin/posts(.:format)              admin/posts#create
  new_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/new(.:format)          admin/posts#new
  edit_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/posts#edit
     admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)          admin/posts#show
                PUT    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)          admin/posts#update
                DELETE /admin/posts/:id(.:format)          admin/posts#destroy
                GET    /admin/posts(.:format)              admin/posts#index

                POST   /admin/posts(.:format)              admin/posts#create
                GET    /admin/posts/new(.:format)          admin/posts#new
                GET    /admin/posts/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/posts#edit
                GET    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)          admin/posts#show
                PUT    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)          admin/posts#update
                DELETE /admin/posts/:id(.:format)          admin/posts#destroy
  admin_backend_index GET    /admin/backend(.:format)            admin/backend#index
                POST   /admin/backend(.:format)            admin/backend#create
  new_admin_backend GET    /admin/backend/new(.:format)        admin/backend#new

  edit_admin_backend GET    /admin/backend/:id/edit(.:format)   admin/backend#edit
  admin_backend GET    /admin/backend/:id(.:format)        admin/backend#show
                PUT    /admin/backend/:id(.:format)        admin/backend#update
                DELETE /admin/backend/:id(.:format)        admin/backend#destroy
     lois_index GET    /lois/index(.:format)               lois#index
      lois_show GET    /lois/show(.:format)                lois#show
    edito_index GET    /edito/index(.:format)              edito#index
  reponses_index GET    /reponses/index(.:format)           reponses#index
  reponses_show GET    /reponses/show(.:format)            reponses#show
  lettres_index GET    /lettres/index(.:format)            lettres#index
   lettres_show GET    /lettres/show(.:format)             lettres#show
       accueils POST   /accueils(.:format)                 accueils#create
   new_accueils GET    /accueils/new(.:format)             accueils#new
  edit_accueils GET    /accueils/edit(.:format)            accueils#edit
                GET    /accueils(.:format)                 accueils#show
                PUT    /accueils(.:format)                 accueils#update
                DELETE /accueils(.:format)                 accueils#destroy
           root        /                                   accueil#index
```

Comment: Can you post what `rake routes` gives you? Or at least the relevant section of it?

Comment: What happens if you try this instead? `<li><%= link_to 'Petitions', admin_petitions %></li>`

Comment: What makes you think it's the second `link_to` that's causing the problem? Can you include an error message pointing to that line?

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto don't forget the _path bit.

Comment: Same error, `Routing Error No route matches {:controller=>"admin/edito"}` with `<%= link_to 'Petitions', admin_petitions %>` ...

Comment: @noodl : No, but they are nothing in common, and the firts `link_yo`drives me where I want.

Comment: Sorry, with `admin_petitions` the error is : `undefined local variable or method `admin_petitions'` . With `admin_petition_path` the error is `Routing Error No route matches {:controller=>"admin/edito"}`

Comment: If you remove this link_to entirely does the page render? Correctly using admin_petition_path should not cause your error. I think it's elsewhere in your page.

Comment: If i write `localhost:3000/admin/petitions` in the url bar, the error is still here. Is it what you meant ?

Comment: You see, the page that contains the link_to renders very well. It's when I click on this link_to that the error occurs.

Comment: Yep, forgot the `_path` indeed. Can you give us the <a> tag that is generated by the link_to?  And the full `rake routes`

Comment: Of course, so here's the <a> generated : `<li><a href="/admin/petitions">Petitions</a></li> ` (I'll edit my post to give you the full rake routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the route names in the left column of your `rake routes`? Use that info to build calls to different path helpers:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Contenu', admin_contents_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Petitions', admin_petitions_path %></li>
```

In general, that's how you should be building URLs in your Rails 3+ app.

Read through [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information (particularly [*2.3: Paths and URLs*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls)).

**Update:**

You should look into using these `_path`-style helpers on the view that's being pulled up when you visit `/admin/petitions`.

I bet you have a link on the page similar to this:

```
<%= link_to "Link Text", :controller => "edito", :action => "index" %>
```

It's trying to find `edito` in the `admin` namespace because that's where you are within the app when you visit `/admin/petitions`.

To fix, you need to update it to read like this:

```
<%= link_to "Link Text", edito_index_path %>
```

Wash, rinse, and repeat for all links, forms, and `url_for` references in your app.

Comment: I would like to ! But it doesn't work with `admin_petitions_path `... But it's ok with `admin_contents_path` I'll use it now, thanks ! Why doesn't it function with petitions ?

Comment: There must be something wrong with another link on `/admin/petitions`. You need to be using this style of linking all throughout the page, not just in the layout. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This was very useful, thank you Chris ! And thank you Noodl and Anthony Alberto ! I apologise for my bad english. Bye